# Is the set of all functions $\mathbb N$ $\to$ $\mathbb Q$ uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$ uncountable?

Comment: Try this: Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ uncountable? There is a bijection between these functions and what?

Comment: ThePortakal is right! If you prefer decimals over binary you could consider all maps from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\subset\mathbb Q$ and whether these are countable or not.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** For any real number $x$ you can define a function $f_x : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ by

$$f_x(n) =\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n} \,.$$

Now, the mapping $x \to f_x$ is a one to one function from $\mathbb R$ to your set.

Comment: Very nice argument.

Answer (score 4):

The cardinality of the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$ is $$|\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}|=|\mathbb Q|^{|\mathbb N|}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c > \aleph_0.$$ 
So this set is uncountable.

See also:

- [Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/is-aleph-0-aleph-0-smaller-than-or-equal-to-2-aleph-0)
- [Is the sets of all maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314682/is-the-sets-of-all-maps-from-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-countable)
- [Comparing the two cardinals $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316530/comparing-the-two-cardinals-aleph-0-aleph-0-and-2-aleph-0)
- [What is $\aleph_0$ powered to $\aleph_0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183513/what-is-aleph-0-powered-to-aleph-0)
- [What's the cardinality of all sequences with coefficients in an infinite set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set)

Some of the above links are taken from: [Overview of basic results on cardinal arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/overview-of-basic-results-on-cardinal-arithmetic/)

---

If you do not want to compute the cardinality of this set, just show that it is not countable, you can use [diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). See, for example, some answers in these questions:

- [The set of natural number functions is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685718/the-set-of-natural-number-functions-is-uncountable)
- [The set of all functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$ is uncountable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304314/the-set-of-all-functions-from-mathbbn-to-0-1-is-uncountable)
- [Show that the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ is not countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129851/show-that-the-set-of-functions-mathbbn-to-0-1-is-not-countable)
- [Infinite Cartesian product of countable sets is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500849/infinite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable)

(You should think a little bit about why showing this for functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$ is equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact you can see it in this way: split the set $A=\{f\colon \mathbb N\to \mathbb N\}$ into $B=\{f\colon \mathbb N\to \mathbb N\colon f(n)=9 \mbox{ eventually}\}$ and $C=A\setminus B$. Then you can map bijectively $C$ to $[0,1)$ by sending $f$ to $0,f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots$ On the other hand, $B$ is countable because it is a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: Do you mean yes?

Comment: @William No, I meant no because I read countable instead of uncountable... Thanks, I'll edit!